# Find location of pair of elements in two arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two `numpy` arrays `x` and `y`

Suppose `x = [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]` and `y = [0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]`

The length of both arrays is the same and the coordinate pair I am looking for definitely exists in the array.

How can I find the index of `(a, b)` in these arrays, where `a` is an element in `x` and `b` is the corresponding element in `y`. For example, the index of `(1, 4)` would be `3`: the elements at index `3` of `x` and `y` are `1` and `4` respectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) combined with [`numpy.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) if you want a purely `numpy` solution:

```
In [16]: import numpy as np

In [17]: x = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])

In [18]: y = np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5])

In [19]: np.where(np.logical_and(x == 1, y == 4))[0]
Out[19]: array([3], dtype=int64)
```

`numpy.logical_and` allows you to element-wise perform a logical AND operation between two numpy arrays.  What we're doing here is determining which locations contain both the `x` values being 1 and the `y` values being 4 in the same corresponding locations.  Those locations that satisfy this are `True`.  `numpy.where` determines the locations in the array where this condition is satisfied.  `numpy.where` actually returns both row and column locations of where the condition is `True` separately as a tuple of two elements, but as we are only considered with one dimension, only the first tuple is valid which is why we immediately index the first element of the tuple.

The output is a `numpy` array of locations where the condition is valid.  You can even go further and coerce the output to be a list of indices to make things neater and/or if it is required (thanks @EddoHintoso):

```
In [20]: list(np.where(np.logical_and(x == 1, y == 4))[0])
Out[20]: [3]
```

Comment: And OP could just coerce the last output into a list by wrapping `list()`. This is the most correct answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare your first array with the first value, second array with the second value and then find where both `True`. Then you could get that `True` with [`argmax`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs9cTM3Z7LAhUGJJoKHQEGCeEQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.0%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.ndarray.argmax.html&usg=AFQjCNFvhA4tINsmwy2vTQmkEscf5zXHJA&bvm=bv.115339255,d.bGs) which will give you first index of the first `True` occurence:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])
y = np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5])
idx = ((x == 1) & (y == 4)).argmax()

In [35]: idx
Out[35]: 3

In [36]: x == 1
Out[36]: array([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [37]: y == 4
Out[37]: array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

If you could have multiple occurence you could use following using `nonzero`:

```
idx_list = ((x == 1) & (y == 4))
idx = idx_list.nonzero()[0]

In [51]: idx
Out[51]: array([3], dtype=int64)
```

Or if you need `list` of indices:

```
In [57]: idx_list.nonzero()[0].tolist()
Out[57]: [3]
```

You could do that in one line with:

```
idx = ((x == 1) & (y == 4)).nonzero()[0]
```

Comment: What if there is more than one possible match for (1,4)?

Comment: @rayryeng Then you could use `nonzero`, edited for that

Comment: Nice. Vote from me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
y = [0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
w=zip(x,y)
w.index((1,4))
```

Comment: numpy solution please